# Tying to access array offset on value of type null in elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php

Tags: elementor

I'm getting an error to access array offset on value of type null in C:\wamp64\www\bc-exe\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php on line 1576 Call Stack
please give me answer

Tying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\wamp64\www\bc-exe\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php on line 1576 Call Stack

Answer (score 0):

From your initial question:
You are trying to access an array offset on a value of type null in the file controls-stack.php at line 1576. This error commonly occurs when you are trying to access an element of an array or a property of an object that is null. Use conditional statements or null-checking techniques

```
if ($myArray !== null && isset($myArray[$index]))
```

From the latest comments:

It's likely because the render() function is being called before the settings are properly initialized.
Are you creating a custom widget based on the Widget_Base class? If so:

```
use \Elementor\Widget_Base;

class Custom_Widget extends Widget_Base 
{
    // Widget code goes here
}
```

Verify that the render() function is implemented correctly within your widget class, make sure the function signature is correct and that it overrides the parent class's render() function:

```
protected function render() 
{
    $settings = $this->get_settings();
    // Rest of your rendering code goes here
}
```

Check if you're registering the widget correctly with Elementor. Make sure you're using the register_widget_type() method to register your widget with Elementor:

```
\Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager- 
>register_widget_type(new Custom_Widget());
```

Ensure that you have set the widget's render_callback correctly when registering it. This callback is responsible for rendering the widget's content. Make sure you have defined the callback function and assigned it to the render_callback property of your widget:

```
class Custom_Widget extends Widget_Base 
{
    // Widget code goes here

    protected function _register_controls() 
    {
        // Register your widget controls
    }

    protected function render() 
    {
        $settings = $this->get_settings();
        // Rest of your rendering code goes here
    }
}

function render_custom_widget($widget) 
{
    $widget_obj = $widget['widgetObj'];
    echo $widget_obj->render_content();
}

\Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager- 
>register_widget_type(new Custom_Widget(
[
    'render_callback' => 'render_custom_widget',
]));
```

You should be able to access the settings using $this->get_settings() within the render() function of your custom widget without encountering an error. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks for your response , actually I'm adding custom widget in elementor plugin so its working fine but when I'm calling this widget default data using a shortcode then giving error

Comment: No problem, maybe share the code for your shortcode implementation. This includes the shortcode callback function, how it is registered, and any relevant code that interacts with your custom widget or retrieves the data. Any additional error messages or the relevant code snippets from your custom widget implementation. To help pinpoint where the issue is exactly :)

Comment: <?php
$widgets_manager = \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->widgets_manager;
$widget_class = $widgets_manager->get_widget_types()['example-widget'];
$widget_instance = new RDS_Services_Widget();
ob_start();
$widget_instance->render();
$output = ob_get_clean();

Comment: There's a few reasons why you're getting this error, maybe rather edit your question and insert the code.. Additionally: Make sure that you have properly registered your custom widget's shortcode in the Elementor plugin.. Make sure your widget class (RDS_Services_Widget) is correctly defined and that it extends the appropriate Elementor widget class. Confirm that the get_widget_types() method provided by Elementor exists in the widgets_manager object and returns the expected widget types..

Comment: Actually its giving me error when I'm using inside the render function $this->get_settings() then this error occurring